# C# write to file

Tags: c#

im tryting to write in to a txt file with C# but i doesnt work. I've searched so many tutorials but none of them actually helped me with my problem.

First of all my problems are actually 2.

**1st:** The method I'm using is not working at all!

**2nd:** From the way my app is working the `OpenFileDialog` is not initialized until a button is clicked. As result my defined `save_to_file()` function has few errors (see the code below)

**CODE**

```
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (savetofile_checkbox.Checked) 
   {
      OpenFileDialog save_to_file = new OpenFileDialog();
      save_to_file.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
      save_to_file.FilterIndex = 2;
      save_to_file.RestoreDirectory = true;
   }
}
```

The purpose of this is to pick a file when you click the checkbox.

This is a bit weird. When you call the function it supposed to write the file in to the file but the `save_to_file` is not defined and in general this way doesn't work and I don't know why..

```
public void write_to_file(string value)
{
   Stream file;

   file_path = save_to_file.FileName;
   file_name = Path.GetFileName(file_path);

   if (save_to_file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)        
   {
      if ((file = save_to_file.OpenFile()) != null)
      {
         TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file_name.ToString());
         tw.WriteLine(value);

         console.AppendText(cur_time() + file_path + "\n");
         console.AppendText(cur_time() + file_name + "\n");

         tw.Close();
         file.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to make this code work?

Comment: why are you using an `OpenFileDialog`?

Comment: you are creating a new local variable inside of the `CheckChanged` event.

Comment: For a start, make `save_to_file` a class member so the value holds over while that class exists. Currently `save_to_file` only belongs to the `CheckChanged` event

Comment: When you write about "function has few erros" please describe error messages and if you encounter them in run-time or build-time.

Answer (score 1):

You define save_to_file variable as a local variable

```
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (savetofile_checkbox.Checked) {

            OpenFileDialog save_to_file = new OpenFileDialog();  //declaration
            save_to_file.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            save_to_file.FilterIndex = 2;
            save_to_file.RestoreDirectory = true;
        } //end of scope of save_to_file variable
    }
```

If I understand correctly you code is not compiling because in write_to_file method variable save_to_file is not defined. What you can do is to declare save_to_file as a field;

```
private OpenFileDialog save_to_file;

private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (savetofile_checkbox.Checked) {

            save_to_file = new OpenFileDialog();  //declaration
            save_to_file.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            save_to_file.FilterIndex = 2;
            save_to_file.RestoreDirectory = true;
        } //end of scope of save_to_file variable
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many sample code availble in google to write to a text file. Why are using Open dailog.. Below is a sample code

```
            string path = @"C:\mytesttext.txt";
            string text2write = "Hello World!";
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
            writer.Write(text2write);
            writer.Close();
```

Comment: Can you please Tell me what is your actual requirment. From your code I am not able to understand anything. As Semao told you are using local varaible globally.